# Add global namespace to psr4 autoloader

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am currently doing something like this:

```
$loader->addPsr4('Application\\Config\\', __DIR__ . '/../config/test');
```

This means I can do any file in the directory `test` with namespace `Application\Config\`.

Is it possible to a similar setup/trick to do this for the global namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$loader->addClassMap(['src\\']);
```

and this will get you all the files in directory `src` (no matter what namespace there will be).